# Conceptual understanding for $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I'm having trouble coming up with a reason, conceptually, for why this identity is true. I know that the left hand side can be thought of as choosing a team of $k$ people from a group of $n$, including one team captain. However, I don't know how I can represent the right side in a similar respect.

Comment: They're both the number of (team, captain) pairs, counted in different ways:
LHS: First choose the $k$ players to make the team, then select which one of the players shall be captain. RHS: First select the captain, then choose the remaining $k-1$ team members from the remaining players

Comment: On the right you choose the captain first. Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: Yes, it all makes sense once you choose the captain first. Thank you all!

Comment: Glad you got the help you need. This is [a very general proof technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)) you will probably find helpful again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [combinational proof for $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}*\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ (not algebraic) Understanding the order that cause division.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534092/combinational-proof-for-binomnk-fracnk-binomn-1k-1-not-algebra)